# Knockout - Unable to parse bindings

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Chrome web developer Console has an error on page opening:

```
Uncaught Error: Unable to parse bindings.
Message: SyntaxError: Unexpected token .;
Bindings value: business.RegistrationViewModel.registerBusiness
```

I have a simple business registration form:
My business registration button  data-binds = "business.RegistrationViewModel.registerBusiness"

My RegistrationViewModel for business looks like this:

```
var business = {};
business.RegistrationViewModel = function (business)
{
    var me = this;
    me.BusinessName = ko.observable('');
    me.BusinessAddress = ko.observable('');
    me.BusinessCity = ko.observable('');
    me.BusinessState = ko.observable('');
    me.BusinessZip = ko.observable('');
    me.RegistrationEmail = ko.observable('');
};
```

And my registration function is this:

```
business.RegistrationViewModel.registerBusiness = function () {
    var me = this;
    var business = ko.toJSON(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: "/RegisterBusiness",
        type: 'post',
        data: business,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        success: function (result) {
            alert("An email has been sent to your email address.");
        }
    });
};
```

My applyBinding function is this:

```
  $(document).ready(function () {
    ko.applyBindings(new business.RegistrationViewModel());
});
```

Did I not write my registerBusiness function correctly?  I am lost as to where this actual error exists.

Comment: `this` in this line `var business = ko.toJSON(this);` gets back the function not your viewmodel. What you get when you breakpoint on this line?

Answer (score 2):

`registerBusiness()` should be on the prototype of `business.RegistrationViewModel`, so define it like this...

```
business.RegistrationViewModel.prototype.registerBusiness = function () {
    var me = this;
    // ...
}
```

Also, because the viewmodel given to `ko.applyBindings()` is a `business.RegistrationViewModel`, you can't include it as part of the binding. Simply use the names of the properties...

```
data-bind="click: registerBusiness"
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ERDDv/)

Edit:

The original declaration of `registerBusiness()`:

```
business.RegistrationViewModel.registerBusiness = function () {
```

puts the function on `business.RegistrationViewModel`, not on any instances of it. If you've done Java or C#, that is sort of like declaring a static method. To declare what is analogous to an instance method, there are 2 options. One is to put a copy of `registerBusiness()` on each instance...

```
business.RegistrationViewModel = function (business)
{
    var me = this;
    // ...
    me.registerBusiness = function () {
        // ...
    };
};
```

Because there is a copy on each instance, memory could be an issue if there are lots of `RegistrationViewModel`s created. The other option is to declare the method on the prototype, which is only created once but accessible by each instance...

```
business.RegistrationViewModel.prototype.registerBusiness = function () {
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Can you elaborate on why it should be a prototype and also, could you give a short synopsis on how I should think about prototyping some of my functions in the future? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Added a bit of an explanation. Hope it helps.